# Bold Chapter bookmark entries in PDF-Reader except LOF

Tags: formatting, bold, bookmarks

I would like to highlight all chapters except the appendix, table of figures and table of tables. I'm using the `bookmark`-package and I tried to set all entries at the `level = 0` to bold and just to turn bold off for the LoF etc. but it seems it has no effect to turn bold off.

[image]

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{
    open,
    addtohook={%
        \ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=0 %
        \bookmarksetup{bold}%
        \fi
    },
}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\pdfbookmark[0]{Content}{toc}
\tableofcontents 
\bookmarksetupnext{bold=false}
\listoffigures  
\newpage

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{I am a figure\label{fig:one}}
\end{figure}
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{I am a figure\label{fig:one}}
\end{figure}

\bookmarksetupnext{bold=false}
\appendix
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline {chapter}{Appendix}{}{}}
\chapter{App 1}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: As I read the documentation, the hook is executed after any options passed to `\bookmark`. So I assume that bold is switched off but then it is switched on again. However, none of the bookmarks are formatted in bold type in my PDF viewer, so I guess the effects may be Adobe-specific or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide an additional toggle (or conditional) that is used in your hook. Below I defined `\ifboldPDFchapters` that you can switch depending on what you need, and added the conditional to the hook:

```
\usepackage{bookmark}

\newif\ifboldPDFchapters

\bookmarksetup{
  open,
  addtohook={%
    \ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=0 %
      \ifboldPDFchapters
        \bookmarksetup{bold}%
      \fi
    \fi
  }
}
```

Adding `\boldPDFchapterstrue` to your document will ensure that all level-0 elements following will be set in **bold**. `\boldPDFchaptersfalse` will remove this setting.

[image]

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{bookmark}

\newif\ifboldPDFchapters

\bookmarksetup{
  open,
  addtohook={%
    \ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=0 %
      \ifboldPDFchapters
        \bookmarksetup{bold}%
      \fi
    \fi
  }
}

\begin{document}

\boldPDFchapterstrue
\pdfbookmark[0]{Content}{toc}
\tableofcontents 

\boldPDFchaptersfalse
\listoffigures  

\boldPDFchapterstrue
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\begin{figure} \caption{I am a figure} \end{figure}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{figure} \caption{I am a figure} \end{figure}

\boldPDFchaptersfalse
\appendix
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline {chapter}{Appendix}{}{}}
\chapter{App 1}

\end{document}
```

It would be possible to incorporate these settings as part of the document commands themselves:

```
\newif\ifboldPDFchapters
\boldPDFchapterstrue% All chapter (level 0) bookmarks are BOLD

\bookmarksetup{
  open,
  addtohook={%
    \ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=0 %
      \ifboldPDFchapters
        \bookmarksetup{bold}%
      \fi
    \fi
  }
}

\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
% ToC bookmark is BOLD
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{{\boldPDFchapterstrue\oldtableofcontents}}
\let\oldlistoffigures\listoffigures
% LoF bookmark is NOT BOLD
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{{\boldPDFchaptersfalse\oldlistoffigures}}
% Appendix onward has chapter bookmarks NOT BOLD
\let\oldappendix\appendix
\renewcommand{\appendix}{\oldappendix\boldPDFchaptersfalse}
```

This allows you to set your document as-is, without any use of switches, or temporary/mid-document changes.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is correct using `addtohook` and `\bookmarksetupnext`. However, `bold=false` of `\bookmarksetupnext` is overwritten by the hook. Therefore `\bookmarksetupnext` must also use the hook:

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{
    open,
    addtohook={%
        \ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=0 %
        \bookmarksetup{bold}%
        \fi
    },
}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\pdfbookmark[0]{Content}{toc}
\tableofcontents
\bookmarksetupnext{addtohook=\bookmarksetup{bold=false}}
\listoffigures
\newpage

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{I am a figure\label{fig:one}}
\end{figure}
\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{I am a figure\label{fig:two}}
\end{figure}

\bookmarksetupnext{addtohook=\bookmarksetup{bold=false}}
\appendix
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline {chapter}{Appendix}{}{}}
\chapter{App 1}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]